# How to configure Font Awesome in Buefy

Tags: vue.js, font-awesome-5, buefy

Can someone let me know some examples of how to add and configure Font Awesome 5 fonts to Buefy using NPM.

The documentation on this is quite sparse. Thanks!

https://buefy.github.io/documentation/start

Comment: What have you tried so for and what where the results?

Answer (score 6):

To use NPM instead of a CDN:

1. Install nuxt-fontawesome.

```
npm i nuxt-fontawesome
npm i @fortawesome/fontawesome-svg-core @fortawesome/vue-fontawesome
```

2. Install an icon set, for example:

```
npm i @fortawesome/free-solid-svg-icons
```

3. Edit nuxt.config.js as follows:

```
modules: [
  'nuxt-buefy',
  'nuxt-fontawesome'
],
buefy: {
  materialDesignIcons: false,
  defaultIconPack: 'fas',
  defaultIconComponent: 'font-awesome-icon'
},
fontawesome: {
  imports: [
    {
      set: '@fortawesome/free-solid-svg-icons',
      icons: ['fas']
    }
  ]
}
```

Usage example:

```
<b-icon pack="fas" icon="home" size="is-large" />
```

Answer (score 0):

I got it working like this in `nuxt.config.js`:

```
  modules: [
    '@nuxtjs/axios',
    '@nuxtjs/router',
    ['nuxt-buefy', {
      css: false,
      materialDesignIcons: false,
      defaultIconComponent: 'vue-fontawesome',
      defaultIconPack: 'fas',
    }],
  ],
```

If you read the nuxt-buefy docs, it shows two ways:

```
{
  modules: [
    // Simple usage
    'nuxt-buefy',

    ['nuxt-buefy', { /* buefy options */ }]
 ]
}
```

or

```
{
  modules: [
    // Simple usage
    'nuxt-buefy',
 ],
 buefy: { /* buefy options */ }
}
```

https://github.com/buefy/nuxt-buefy